# URL to generate random image on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, social-media

I'm a newbie to wordpress and tried a few things without success.
I want to have a special page on my wordpress to generate a single random image from a specific category or post-type. http://lorempixel.com is a great example of what I need: basically a set of URLs to return an image.

Appreciate if someone can point me out in the right direction!

Just in case someone asks, this will be useful to use on automatic social media posts :)

Many thanks

Paulo

Answer (score 0):

the idea is using random number generator and switch case

here might be the example of the idea, you can swap the content to whatever you want such as your random picture

```
$amountOfDigits = 8;
$numbers = range(1,8);
shuffle($numbers);


switch ($numbers){
    case '1':
        $content = 'pic 1....';
        break;
    case '2':
        $content = 'pic 2....';
        break;
    case '3':
        $content = 'pic 3....';
        break;
    case '4':
        $content = 'pic 4....';
        break;
    case '5':
        $content = 'pic 5....';
        break;
    case '6':
        $content = 'pic 6....';
        break;
    case '7':
        $content = 'pic 7....';
        break;
    case '8':
        $content = 'pic 8....';
        break;      
}
```

Comment: Thanks @NigelXu, that might be a good start but I need to figure out how to output this with a unique URL, just like http://lorempixel.com.